# Symfony 6.3 : html_sanitizer scoped service

Tags: containers, phpunit, symfony6

I want to call in a PHPUnit KernelTestCase `setUp` method, the service `html_sanitizer` from the services' container.

```php
public function setUp(): void
{
    parent::setUp(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
    $this->project = new Project();
    $container = self::getContainer();
    $this->htmlSanitizer = $container->get('html_sanitizer.sanitizer.app.project_sanitizer');
}
```

I've configured in `html_sanitizer.yaml` an `html_sanitizer` service as per [Symfony — HTML Sanitizer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/html_sanitizer.html):

```yaml
# config/packages/html_sanitizer.yaml

  framework:
      html_sanitizer:
      sanitizers:
          app.project_sanitizer:
      allow_elements:
          article: ['class', 'data-attr']
          img: 'src'
          h1: '*'
```

When I run `symfony console debug:container`, the service `html_sanitizer.sanitizer.default` is present. But not the configured one, `html_sanitizer.sanitizer.app.project_sanitizer`.

What's wrong?

Comment: The same issue and it is not indentation problem. If I mess identation, i am getting identation. But confing is not autowired.  php bin/console debug:container html_sanitizer result is:  Service ID       html_sanitizer.sanitizer.default

Answer (score -1):

I think you have an indentation error in the YAML. With the following YAML html_sanitizer.sanitizer.app.project_sanitizer is available.

```yaml
framework:
  html_sanitizer:
    sanitizers:
      app.project_sanitizer:
        allow_elements:
          article: ['class', 'data-attr']
          img: 'src'
          h1: '*'
```

```bash
# bin/console debug:container
...
html_sanitizer.config.app.project_sanitizer   Symfony\Component\HtmlSanitizer\HtmlSanitizerConfig 
...
```